# Compare col 1 and 2 with another table

Tags: excel-formula

How can I compare 2 columns from one sheet with another sheet and copy the 3rd column from the 2nd sheet to the 1st sheet? 
If no data found and match, a word of "error" should be shown.

=VLOOKUP(E4&F4,$AP$4:$AQ$125,3,0)

[image: Table 1 and 2]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This formula solved the problem.

=IF(AND(E4="",F4=""),"",IFERROR(INDEX($AR:$AR,MATCH(1,INDEX(($E4=$AP:$AP)*($F4=$AQ:$AQ),0),0)),"No Found"))

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Lets see if I understood your right...
I did not bother separate the tables on two sheets just ad sheetName! before any address to make it work.

on a Swedish machine

```
=IF(MATCH(A2;F:F;)=MATCH(B2;G:G;);INDIRECT("H"+MATCH(B2;G:G;));"error")
```

This function is more international i suppose

```
=IF(MATCH(A2,F:F,)=MATCH(B2,G:G,),INDIRECT("H"+MATCH(B2,G:G,)),"error")
```

[image]

Comment: =IF(MATCH(A2;F:F;)=MATCH(B2;G:G;);INDIRECT("H"+MATCH(B2;G:G;));"error") Tried your formula but received an error saying not trying to type a formula. The error highlighted =IF(MATCH(A2....

Comment: It could be that you must use a "," rather than ";" in the formula. That is dependent on your language and region settings.

Answer (score 0):

I am using this formula:
=IF(MATCH(A2,F:F,)=MATCH(B2,G:G,),INDIRECT("H",+MATCH(B2,G:G,)),"error")
and I have this result:-

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7xByz.jpg)

Comment: using this formula instead except cannot get the "error" display if not found. =IF(OR(E34="",F34=""),"",INDEX(AR:AR,MATCH(E34&F34,AP:AP&AQ:AQ,0)))